# unique validation not working, how do I..?

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I am using Doctrine 2.2.1 and CodeIgniter 2.1.0

I am attempting to do unique validation on an email address field from a form - simply to make sure that the field does not already exist in the database.

I started by checking this good (but outdated) tutorial [here](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-scratch-day-3-user-signup-form) and the CodeIgniter documentation [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

The CI documentation shows examples using is_unique[table.field]  and also seems to say that using a callback can do this but I don't seem to be grasping how that code does it, and I cannot make it work myself.

I have tried this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail',
                 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

and this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'callback_email_check');
```

(which is cribbed almost verbatim from the CodeIgniter example)

Neither work.  The first gives me the following output:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Signup_form::$db

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 954


Fatal error: Call to a member function limit() on a non-object in /../systemFolder/libraries/Form_validation.php on line 954
```

The second gives me this output:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'email@address.com' for key 'email_index'' in /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:131 Stack trace: #0 /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php(131): PDOStatement->execute(NULL) #1 /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php(239): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute() #2 /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(896): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() #3 /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(304): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata in /../applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php on line 131

Am I overlooking something simple?  Any help with how to correctly do a unique validation against the DB with CI/Doctrine?  Thanks!

**Note:   I was able to get `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');` working after adding 'database' to the autoload config, however, this breaks Doctrine entirely.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem.  Not sure if it is the best or most elegant way, but it works.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 
                 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
```

```
public function email_check($str)
{
$user = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->findOneBy(array('email' => $str));
    if (isset($user)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'This email address is already in use');
                    return FALSE;
    } else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this same problem, it was an issue with CodeIgniter 2.1.
There are two fixes for it.

**1.** Upgrade CodeIgniter from the repo source, it has the fix for it and many other fixes for other problems:
[Repo Source at Github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter)

*or*

**2.** Open `system/libraries/Form_validation`
Go to line `954` and replace the function `is_unique()` with:

```
    public function is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        list($table, $field) = explode('.', $field);

        if (isset($this->CI->db)) {
            $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
            return $query->num_rows() === 0;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**here is 100% working solution:**

->go to system/libraries/form_validation.php

->go to line no 954 (your may be arround 950s)

->Replace is_unique function with following code

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        list($table, $field)=explode('.', $field);
        $this->CI->load->database('default');

        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));

        return $query->num_rows() === 0;
    }
```

**Actually** Error was because of unknown $db object because there was no database loaded before calling $db.

Answer (score 0):

As for me solution is in the table name "User", in your validation rule it must be : `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail',             'required|valid_email|is_unique[Users.email]');` - table name is uppercased. 
I hope this helps someone.

Also in CodeIgniter 2.0 you should use:

```
 is_unique[db,table_name,field_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$this->load->database();` in the `_construct` function